# What does $SL_2(\mathbb{F}_q)/\{I,-I\}$ look like?

Tags: group-theory

I am not sure what the elements of 
$$SL_2(\mathbb{F}_q)\big/\left\{ \begin{pmatrix}1&0\\0&1\end{pmatrix},\begin{pmatrix}-1&0\\0&-1\end{pmatrix}\right\}$$
 look like for an arbitrary prime $q$.

Could someone write down explicitly this group for a small $q$ (or explain it if that's not feasible)? I think that would help me understand how it behave for any arbitrary prime $q$.

I ask this in the context of Ramanujan graphs. Lubotzky, Phillips and Sarnark showed that when taking the Cayley graph of this group with respect to a family of suitably chosen generator of order $p+1$ (with $p$ prime and $p\neq q$) then we get an infinite family of d-regular Ramanujan graphs. But to see what those families look like I have to understand the shape of the group above.

Comment: Clearly the group has order q*(q-1)/2 and the this group is a simple group as long as q is greater than or equal to 5.

Comment: @HumbleStudent : Actually, the order is $\frac{q(q-1)(q+1)}{2}$ ( for $q$ odd).

Comment: You are basically looking at $2 \times 2$ matrices of determinant $1$ over the field of $q$ elements, except that for such a matrix $M$, the two matrices $M$ and $-M$ are identified. I don't know if there is really a simpler way to explain it.

Comment: What's more explicit than what you've already written? Matrices are very, very explicit. The way people understand other groups is often by writing their elements in terms of matrices.

Comment: @GeoffRobinson Thanks a lot, that's what I was looking for. I had difficulties seeing what matrices where identified with $I$ and $-I$, and now I see it.

Comment: You can also think of it as a doubly transitive permutation group on the $q+1$ points of the projective line.

Comment: @GeoffRobinson  oops!! I should have reread my comment after posting. I meant to say q(q^2 - 1) /2. I am pretty sure about the simple part.

Comment: @HumbleStudent : You are certainly correct about the simple claim!